# How to open a web URL from a script which requires single sign on

Tags: asp.net, jsp, cookies, single-sign-on

I want to extract a report from a internal web page. I have a direct URL which will download the report. But it needs the cookie of the single sign on to work. How can I make the single sign on happen if I want to use the report URL in a script?

Comment: single sign on? you mean "logging in", "signing in" to your system?

Comment: Not exactly the system. When I enter the homepage URL, the authentication happens by validating the user name from LDAP which in-turn validates my profile with SSO server. After that it creates a session in the cookie file. Then if I enter the direct report URL, it executes. But the problem is, if the cookie is not yet created and if I enter the report URL, then it wont login.

Answer (score 0):

So why you just don't check for session value?

```
if (Session["user_id"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("Login");
```

Do something like this. If user will not have an session value, it means that he didn't authorized yet, and this page will redirect him automatically to login page. Otherwise it will work as it have to work. Add this check to your Page_Load function, it should be earlier than any other construction.